# Do unlockables run out?

Tags: mass-effect-3, mass-effect-3-multiplayer

In multi-player, if you get all of the weapons, mods, characters and appearance mods of a rarity what happens? Do you get those of the lowest other available level? Do you just get consumables?

Answer (score 7):

If you unlock enough cards to reach rank X on a weapon or rank V on a weapon mod, it *is* removed from the pool, and it is no longer possible to find it.

This also works with consumable supply increases (up to +5), and character respec cards (if you have 3 unused respec cards in your inventory, you can't get any more).

What *doesn't* get removed from the pool are the character cards, because even after unlocking all of the appearence options for a given character, you still benefit from the class XP (more xp from rarer packs!) each time you find a class character card.

Comment: 12500 xp for recruit, 50k for veterans, 100k for the spectre. just to be more specific about that :) also: after you unlocked everything, you should try to buy packages only when you have chars between level 1-16, since the the character cards will help you level up fast again throu the first levels :)

Comment: So you still get the cards even with max level for the calss AND all appearance options?

Comment: @BenBrocka unfortunately, yes.